How can I take a screenshot of something
I would like to take a screenshot of something, but I do not know how. It says on google to find the system menu, but I do not know what that is. Can anybody please help (If it helps, I am running Ubuntu 22.04.5)

You mention a release, but no clue as to product which is very important... eg. If using Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE etc, even if the same release (22.04.5) they'll use different apps...  The easiest way is just pressing , but the effects of that can vary depending on your setup too  (on my current setup my screens just darkened a little & an instruction asking what I want to printscreen appeared). On some devices there is no PrintScreen key as its there as a Fn. option using other keys (this is device specific! refer your docs)

Did you try your PrtScr button?
